# How do i merge changes to directories when making a pull request and then merging?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have multi-user repository and each user has his own directory, as well as branch. For example:

master

- DirectoryA
- DirectoryB

BranchA (used by UserA)

- DirectoryA (used by UserA)
- DirectoryB

BranchB (used by UserB)

- DirectoryA
- DirectoryB (used by UserB)

Initially, the master branch has files in each directories, then Branch A and B were created. UserA has modified files in his folder in his BranchA, while UserB has modified files in his folder in his BranchB.

How do I create pull requests to the master branch such that the changes made by UserA in DirectoryA located in BranchA is preserved to the master, while UserB in DirectoryB located in BranchB is also preserved?

Comment: I don't understand your question entirely, but if you are using a repo like GitHub or Bitbucket, then all you need to do is push the branch and create a PR from the website.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be any problem with the usual workflow. UserA hasn't touched directory B so his pull request will not contain any changes for B. A pull request from UserB will not change directory A. No problem so far.

But after both PRs are accepted both users must update — and UserA will fetch changes in directory B while UserB will pull changes for directory A.